# How to understand the noun phrase "a touch heavy-handed"?

Tags: meaning

From Graham King. (2000). Good Punctuation. p.113.

> If this chapter on hyphens has seemed **a touch heavy-handed** you might consider the words of writer and grammatical realist Keith Waterhouse: 'If you write *second-hand* and *car salesman*, should you write *second-hand-car salesman*, which is fussy, or *second-hand car salesman*, which suggests that the salesman is second-hand? Fruitless hours can be spent pondering such questions. It is usually-better to leave all the hyphens out than allow them to pile up.

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

Should it be "a heavy-handed touch"? If so, why does "heavy-handed" follow "touch"? If not, what is the usage?

Comment: No: they have different meanings, a heavy-handed touch" being far stronger than "a touch heavy-handed". "A touch heavy-handed" is not a noun phrase but an adjective phrase with the complex determinative functioning here as modifier of the compound adjective "heavy-handed". Compare also "a little heavy-handed", which has the same meaning and the same stucture.

Comment: See Merriam Webster no/ 7

Comment: As everyone has explained, the modifier "touch" simply means "slightly". That's all there is to it. For example, you might say "give us a touch more volume please" or "drive a touch faster please" or "coffee is better with a touch of sugar".

Comment: @Fattie It's not "touch" but "a touch", a complex determinative.

Comment: @Winged Tiger. I'm afraid you've approved the wrong answer. The expression is not "touch" but "a touch", which is a complex determinative in the same way that "a little" is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [1] *If this chapter on hyphens has seemed a touch heavy-handed* ...
>
> [2] *If this chapter on hyphens has seemed a heavy-handed touch ...*

[1] and [2] have quite different meanings, *a heavy-handed touch* being far stronger than *a touch heavy-handed*, as well as having a somewhat different meaning. In [1] *a touch heavy-handed* relates 'to this chapter on hyphens' where the meaning of *a touch* is similar to *a little*, while, by contrast, in [2] the heavy-handedness relates to *touch*, which here is a noun.

I'd say that [1] conveys the intended meaning, where *a touch heavy-handed* is not a noun phrase but an adjective phrase with the complex determinative "a touch" functioning here as modifier of the compound adjective "heavy-handed".

The head of the adjective phrase is *heavy-handed* which requires a modifier (here, *a touch*) to be in attributive (pre-head) position.

Compare also *if this chapter on hyphens has seemed a little heavy-handed ...*, where the complex determinative *a little* has more or less the same meaning here as *a touch.*

Comment: Where is Noun after indefinite article "a"?

Comment: @Sam "A touch" is a complex determinative in the same way that "a little" is.

Comment: The second one would more naturally be ".. seemed to have a .."

Comment: Yes, I think 'a touch' is the same as 'a little' as a whole.

Comment: The paenultimate paragraph here seems wrong, or at least ambiguous. _Heavy-handed_ isn’t in attributive position – it’s predicative. And even if it were, it wouldn’t require a modifier to be so (in fact complex modifiers like _a touch_ would be disallowed: ‘*an a touch heavy-handed chapter’ is ungrammatical). Is the intended meaning rather that any modifiers to the head in an adjective phrase are required to be in attributive position? (And does that mean you don’t consider postpositional PPs like ‘heavy-handed in the extreme’ to modify the head?)

Comment: Also, I take it you would still consider the complex determinative _a touch_ to be internally made up of a NP with a determiner and a head noun, correct? Given that similar complex determinatives (though not really _a touch_ itself) can incorporate modifiers to the noun (e.g., ‘a bit/tad heavy-handed’ → ‘a tiny bit/tad heavy-handed’), that seems inevitable to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Seems right -- touch, tad, bit all seem to be nouns that have been adverbed.

Comment: I didn’t say that “heavy-handed” is attributive -- of course it isn’t. What I said (or meant to say) was that it requires the modifier “a touch” to be in attributive position. I should have made that clearer. It’s the whole AdjP (“a touch heavy-handed”) that is predicative. In other AdjPs, the modifier may be post-head, as is often the case. “A touch” can take internal modification e.g. “a slight touch heavy-handed”.

Comment: [2] If this chapter on hyphens has seemed a heavy-handed touch… is not just different from [1] If this chapter on hyphens has seemed a touch heavy-handed…

Simply, [1] is fine and [2] is so obviously wrong, it could never be correct.

Your [2] needs instead to read: 'If this chapter on hyphens has seemed heavy-handed…'

Do you see the difference?

Comment: Of course I can see the difference! If you'd read my answer closely you'd have realised that [2] is not _my_ suggestion but that of the OP which I simply copied for comparison purposes. [1] is the correct alternant here, which is what I said.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this is really a question about hyphenation.

In the phrase

> a touch heavy-handed

the "touch" is an adverb meaning "just a little" modifying the adjective "heavy-handed".

The phrase

> a heavy-handed touch

suggests a very heavy hand.

> 7 : something slight of its kind:    a touch of fever
> a small quantity or indication :  touch of spring
> in the air

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touch

Comment: Where is Noun after indefinite article "a"?

Comment: The noun is "heavy-handed" (the object of the verb "seemed:, The adjective "touch" precedes the noun. That's like the sentence "I seem to be a little sleepy today."

Comment: a touch, a little, a bit

Comment: isn't a word that modifies an adjective called an adverb?

Comment: @user253751 I thought about that. In this case I think "heavy-handed" works as the noun object of the sentence. I might be wrong about that since I haven't studies formal grammar since about 8th grade many years ago.

Comment: @EthanBolker heavy-handed is certainly an adjective. I don't see how it can be anything else.

Comment: @user253751You're probably right. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: "A touch" is best analysed as a complex determinative functioning here as modifier. of the compound adjective "heavy-handed".

Comment: @BillJ Nice to hear from a grammarian.

Comment: @BillJ I'm tempted to declare *a touch* in constructions like this one ("a touch <adjective>") **an adverb**. Usage, meaning and derivation from a noun is exactly parallel to [the adverb "a bit"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20bit) ("a touch heavy-handed" = "a bit heavy-handed"). This is to be distinguished from all the examples given in the dictionaries which use "a touch *of* something", where *touch* is used as a noun.

Comment: @BillJ Ah, I see that FriendlyRaccoon made that point as well, although they seem to include "a touch *of*" in the adverbial uses. [M-W categorizes *bit* in " a bit *of* a rascal" as a noun.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bit)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I take "a touch" to be like the indisputable complex determinative "a little". Compare "I was a touch hasty" ~ "I was a little hasty". Note that although determinatives usually function as determiners, some of them can also function as modifiers.

Comment: @BillJ This is a bit out of my grammar comfort zone -- but I note that M-W carries "a little" as an adverb, just like "a bit" but unlike "a touch". Obviously, language is evolving, and this use of "touch" may have become more popular "recently" (in terms of dictionary writing times). At least, I find it "modern".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Never trust dictionaries for grammar, especially M-W, a dinosaur of a dictionary that has failed to keep up with the classification of words. M-W are absolutely wrong about this. "Little" is clearly a degree determinative in "I have little money", and "a little" is a complex paucal determinative in "I have a little money". In both cases the deterninative is functioning as a determiner. The complex form can also function as a modifier (as opposed to a determiner) , as in "He answered a little indiscreetly", as can "a touch" as in the OP's example.

Comment: I suggest adding an example to the answer, for an alternative way to express the same thing, as the OP seemingly misunderstood the entire structure. It has nothing to do with touching anything, or any kind of touch. It's the same as writing *"If this chapter on hyphens has seemed **slightly heavy-handed** you might consider... "*

Answer (score 8):

This can definitely be confusing! Let's break it down - the word **touch** is being used as an adverb here to describe the phrase "heavy-handed." You might say "isn't touch usually a verb that means to physically come into contact with something?" You're right! but in this case it means something different.

### **Touch as an Adjective or Adverb**

In this case, **touch** is being used as a measurement to mean "a little" or "a small amount." You'll see this word used in the same way in phrases like:

- "Add a **touch** of wine to the sauce."
- "My house is pretty clean but just needs a **touch** of tidying."

Some synonyms are

- tad
- smidge
- little bit

### Heavy-Handed

The phrase **heavy-handed** usually means "overdone," "overly controlled," or "not elegant." This shows up in a wide range of contexts, from cooking, to writing, to politics. Here are some other examples:

- "That speech was **heavy-handed**, the president gave too many metaphors and it felt like she was lecturing the audience."
- "Don't be too **heavy-handed** with the cream in the soup. We only want a little bit."
- "He is such a **heavy-handed** driver - I feel like I am constantly being thrown around in his car."

### Putting it Together

In this case, the author saying "a touch heavy-handed" means "a little bit overdone" or "a little bit too much." They might mean that the thing being talked about was almost right and only ended up in the overdone category by accident, or they might be using sarcasm and mean that it was actually very overdone.

Comment: Where is Noun after indefinite article "a"?

Comment: @Sam This is one example of English breaking its own general rules. Usually only nouns have articles. In this case "a touch" is a phrase that is being used as an adverb. It would not sound correct to a native speaker if you just said "this is touch heavy-handed." This phrase is always used with the indefinite article "a."

Comment: I think it's better to classify "a touch" as a complex determinative functioning as a modifier of the compound adjective "heavy-handed".